# Possible duplicate question

Tags: discussion

I would like to point out that this question: [“Normal” variables in Upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368311/normal-variables-in-upstart) could be a duplicate of this other question: [Expand variables in upstart script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70882/expand-variables-in-upstart-script).

I tested on lubuntu 12.04 and bug is still present.

I hope this is the right place for this type of report.

Comment: Yes, that does appear to be a duplicate to me.

Comment: "I hope this is the right place for this type of report." nope ;) flagging it would be the way to go :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind: oh! flag link after edit at the end of question? Sorry I thought that was for other kind of situation because tooltip said "serious problem". Next time I'll do so, thanks.

Comment: @Letizia Yes, the tooltip is a little confusing. You can also ask questions like these in [chat].

Comment: @Seth: I flagged a question as duplicate, but nothing happens. I'm curious, how are handled reports made via flag link?

Comment: @Letizia Questions flagged "it is a duplicate" or "it should be closed for another reason" aren't shown directly to moderators, but are fed into a [close vote queue](http://askubuntu.com/review/close/) where users with >3k reputation (and moderators) can review them. Unfortunately, this queue is rather backlogged at the moment, currently containing over 700 posts, which is why these flags can take a while to get processed.

Comment: @Seth: thanks, I supposed, but I was not sure. So... good job! :)